# Higher z-index appearing below lower z-index

Tags: html, css, z-index

What would make a html element e.g. an ul aboslutely positioned with a zindex of say 5000 to appear below a div of a lower zindex say 0? This behaviour is seen in IE8.

Answer (score 15):

Just because it has a higher z-index doesn't mean it'll be on top. You have to take into account the parent's stacking level and this becomes the stacking context. Try giving a non-static position ( relative ) to the parent of the 5000.

If that doesn't work, post the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example [Absolute elements ignore z-index in IE6 and IE7](http://starikovs.com/2011/04/13/absolute-elements-ignore-z-index-in-ie6-and-ie7/). May be you will find something usfull in this sample.